# ¿Cómo poner vectores en un Objeto?

Tags: java, string, object

Necesito asignar los valores de varios vectores en un objeto:

```
public static void crearPokemon(){
    if(contador<=4){
        contador=contador+1;
        System.out.println("Has elegido crear tu pokemon numero "+ (contador+1) + " solo puedes crear 5 pokemon.");
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de su Pokemon");
        nombreDelPokemon[contador]=scanner.next();
        hpDelPokemonTotal[contador]=generadorAleatorio(50,100);
        hpDelPokemonActual[contador]=hpDelPokemonTotal[contador];
        nivelDelPokemon[contador]=0;
        saludDelPokemon[contador]=calcularSalud(contador,hpDelPokemonActual[contador]);
        System.out.println("Ingrese la imagen de su Pokemon");
        scanner.useDelimiter("¬");
        imagenDelPokemon=scanner.next();
        scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
        System.out.println("Tu Pokemon se creo correctamente. *.-.*");
    }
```

En este código tengo el procedimiento para crear un Pokemon a partir de valores que el jugador ingresa, y la condicional que esta allí, es para que el límite de pokemon creados no sobrepase de cinco.

También tengo el siguiente constructor:

```
public Pokemon (String nombreDelPokemon,int hpDelPokemonTotal,int hpDelPokemonActual,int nivelDelPokemon,int saludDelPokemon, String imagenDelPokemon){
}
```

Pero no se si está bien escrito.

El arreglo de objeto es el siguiente:

```
static String mascota []= new String[5];
```

Y la instanciación de mi objeto la quiero hacer así:

```
    Pokemon mascota[contador]=new Pokemon(nombreDelPokemon[contador],hpDelPokemonTotal[contador],hpDelPokemonActual[contador], nivelDelPokemon[contador],saludDelPokemon[contador],imagenDelPokemon[contador]);
```

el error que me da es:

> ']' expected
>
> ';' expected
>
> New instance ignored

Comment: Esto es Java, ¿verdad?

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar el mensaje de error completo y no sólo ese corto extracto? ¿En qué líneas da ese error? ¿Ambos errores en la misma línea? ¿Y la línea anterior qué tiene? (es probable que el error sea efecto secundario de un error en la línea anterior). ¿En tu código tienes `static String mascota []= new String[5];` o `static String[] mascota = new String[5];`? Si es lo primero, estás cometiendo un error de sintaxis.

Comment: @OscarGarcia querrás decir `static Pokemon[] mascota = new Pokemon[5]`, ¿no?

Comment: No, @cpinamtz, pero eso que has puesto me ha hecho ver que la línea `Pokemon mascota[contador]=new Pokemon ..` está mal porque está definiendo un tipo y al mismo tiempo asignando un valor a uno de sus índices, cosa que no se puede hacer.

Answer (score 2):

Estás confundiendo definición de tipos y asignación de un valor.

Para empezar estás tratando de crear una matriz de cadenas con:

```
static String mascota []= new String[5];
```

Pero si lo que quieres es crear una matriz de `Pokemon` entonces debes usar:

```
static Pokemon[] mascota = new Pokemon[5];
```

Por otro lado, deseas crear una instancia de `Pokemon` con:

```
Pokemon mascota[contador] = new Pokemon(...);
```

Cuando lo normal es no usar definición de tipo de nuevo en la asignación:

```
mascota[contador] = new Pokemon(...);
```

Hacerlo provoca un error al compilar.

---

Por lo tanto, arreglando ambos errores, tu código debería ser:

```
static Pokemon[] mascota = new Pokemon[5];
mascota[contador] = new Pokemon(...);
```

Comment: `static String mascota []= new String[5];` es sintaxis válida. Los corchetes pueden ir a cualquier lado del nombre de variable. Aunque se recomienda que esten al lado del tipo

Comment: Gracias @Klaimmore. Revisando [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) he visto que es cierto. Llevo tanto tiempo haciéndolo de la otra forma que pensaba que podría ser uno de los orígenes del problema.

Comment: Gracias amigos, si me funciono la solucion. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Un placer @FuentesVillatoroKevinJosue . Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta si te solucionó el problema.